# Can you use modulo with Propel Criteria?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, criteria, propel

I want to skip 'N' rows when I pull data.  Using raw SQL I can accomplish this using`WHERE 'id' %%%u=0` where 'u' is my interval. Can I accomplish this using the Criteria object?  I've tried this: `$c->getNewCriterion(GaugeDataPeer::ID%$interval, 0, Criteria::EQUAL);` but to no avail.

This is on Symfony 1.4. Not sure what Propel version.

Here's the full query I'm trying to recreate:

```
$query  = sprintf("SELECT *
                          FROM `processed_gauge_data`
                          WHERE `id` %%%u=0 AND `processed_gauge_data`.`gauge_id` IN (%s) AND `processed_gauge_data`.`stamp` >= '%s' AND `processed_gauge_data`.`stamp` <= '%s';",
                  $interval,
                  implode(',', $gauge),
                  mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start)),
                  mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end))
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `->where`

```
->where('ProcessedGaugeData.Id %%%u = 0')
```

and better use ActiveQuery: http://propelorm.org/blog/2010/08/03/refactoring-to-propel-1-5-from-peer-classes-to-query-classes.html

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution!

MY OLD CODE:

```
$c = new Criteria();
            $c->add(GaugeDataPeer::GAUGE_ID, $this->getId(), Criteria::EQUAL);

            $start_c = $c->getNewCriterion(GaugeDataPeer::STAMP, $dates['start']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
            $end_c = $c->getNewCriterion(GaugeDataPeer::STAMP, $dates['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
            $start_c->addAnd($end_c);
            $c->add($start_c);

            $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(GaugeDataPeer::STAMP);
            $data_array = GaugeDataPeer::doSelect($c);
```

MY NEW CODE

```
$query  = sprintf("SELECT *
                          FROM `gauge_data`
                          WHERE `id` %%%u=0 AND `gauge_data`.`gauge_id` IN (%s) AND `gauge_data`.`stamp` >= '".$dates['start']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' AND `gauge_data`.`stamp` <= '".$dates['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."';",
                  $interval,
                  implode(',', array($this->getId()))
              );                

            $conn = Propel::getConnection();
            $st = $conn->prepare($query);
            $st->execute();
            $data_array = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, GaugeData);
```